# 'username_exists' function not working in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanna use "username_exists" in my own plugin but when I use this function I got this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_user_by()
>   in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\user.php:1271 Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\register-plus\index.php(86):
>   username_exists('admin') #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php(255):
>   include_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php(89):
>   require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #3
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #4
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(13):
>   require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #5
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17):
>   require('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 {main} thrown in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\user.php on line 1271

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Is this function is WP or custom?

Comment: this i a WP function ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists )

Comment: Ok. you will call your plugin right?  i think that function is not included your plugin

Comment: i think too. but i don't know how and what include in my plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I include 'pluggable.php' in my plugin and problem fixed

```
include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
```